# How to remove this fluorescent lamp from its fixture

Tags: light-fixture, lamp, fluorescent

**tl/dr: I can't find how to release the lamp from the fixture.**

- **Not spring-loaded**
- **Non rotating**
- **I can't find a way to remove the sides**

I have a fluorescent lamp in my bathroom which lights up about 2 minutes after I turn the switch on, so I have to change the starter.

The problem is that the fixture is not a regular one with a slit where you just rotate the lamp to get it out. Also, it's not spring-loaded (I tried to push it to both directions), and I haven't found a way to pull one of the sides out to release the lamp (this was my initial thought as it has some kind of clips/buttons that I can't figure out if they have something to do with the sides or they just hold the bay cover under the lamp).

Lamp model: Osram Lumilux Plus 36W/41-827
I can't find any info on the model of the fixture

Also, [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147424/how-do-i-get-the-fluorescent-bulb-out-of-this-fixture) didn't help.

[image: left side]

[image: right side - a bit out of focus]

[image: right side]

Comment: Those buttons obviously release _something_. While squeezing both such that they feel like they've disengaged, try removing the endcap.

Comment: @isherwood I tried that to both sides (there are four of them, two in each side), but the endcaps aren't moving, that's why I think they might hold the bay cover.

Comment: I'd be surprised if one of us has specific experience with that old light. Thousands of such fixtures have been designed and sold over the decades. Keep wiggling things and something will come apart.

Comment: You've done a great job of giving us the model of the _bulb_. How about the make/model of the fixture itself? Also, if something comes apart (as @isherwood noted) but wasn't _supposed_ to come apart, a similar replacement fixture shouldn't be too terribly expensive. ;)

Comment: Is it possible that you pull the button/clips instead of pushing? Do they move side-to-side? I wouldn't think it, but have you tried removing the long panels between the plastic end caps?

Comment: @FreeMan I found no info about the model of the fixture.
Either pushing or pulling the clips doesn't seem to change anything (like releasing any part).
The long panels are metal and seem like it's one metal sheet bent in "Π" shape, where everything is mounted on.

Comment: that looks like a disposable light fixture ... the lamp is probably not supposed to be replacable .... check for labels on the fixture

Comment: 36 w osram is a standard lamp size I know of 2 styles one pulls to 1 end like spring loaded pull the tube to the right no movement pull to the left based on the photo. If that doesn’t work I would try and see if the clips release the cover so the lamp can then be twisted and removed. Those are the only options that I am aware of with that lamp. Standard 36w 827 is the color reference

Comment: I bet you push the buttons, and the end cap moves UP, then you can pull it off.

Comment: @jsotola I thought that too, but then -- how is power connected to it?  The cheapies I remember had cords.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica you are right ... I totally missed the invisible power cord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a struggle, hell of, but I managed to remove the bulb by sliding out the anchor while pressing the two clips. I needed to shake the whole assembly in order to get it out. Good luck! [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! After so many years the endcaps were adhered to the fixture.